# Remove an array entry in an object using spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I recently spent some time trying to use the `$pull` operator through Spring's Data MongoOperations interface, so I thought it would be nice to share my findings in case anyone bumps into a similar problem.

So here it goes...

I have 2 java POJOs like so :

```
@Document
public class OutterObject{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<InnerDocument> innerDocs;


    //SETTERS - GETTERS Ommited


public class InnerDocument{


    private String id;
    private String name;

         //SETTERS - GETTERS Ommited
```

This is stored in a Mongo collection like so :

```
 "_id" : "doc2",
 "_class" : "OutterObject",
 "name" : "doc2",
 "innerDocs" : [{
      "_id" : "innerDoc21",
      "name" : "innerDoc21"
  }, {
      "_id" : "innerDoc22",
      "name" : "innerDoc22"
  }]
```

I'm trying to use the $pull operator in order to remove all objects inside the innerDoc collection having a name value = "innerDoc22".

I know how to accomplish this using the mongo driver like so :

```
 List<String> ids = 
         Arrays.asList("innerDoc22");

 BasicDBObject find = new BasicDBObject();

 match.put("innerDocs.name", 
           BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$in", ids).get());

    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
        update.put(
                "$pull",
                BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("innerDocs",
                        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("name", "innerDoc22").get()).get());

  DBCollection col= mongoOperations.getDb().getCollection("outterObject");

  col.update(find , update);
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing using Spring's MongoOperations Interface.
Here is my code using the MongoOperations interface :

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("innerDoc22");

Query removeQuery = Query.query(Criteria.where("innerDocs.name").in(ids));

WriteResult wc = mongoOperations.upsert(
                    removeQuery, 
                    new Update().pull("innerDocs.name", "innerDoc22"), 
                    OutterObject.class);
System.out.println(wc.getLastError());
```

I'm not getting any errors when calling `getLastError()` the update is simply not done in the database.

I know a similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097621/remove-an-entry-from-array-using-mongodb-java-driver) but the answer that was given does not use the MongoOperations interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching a bit and looking at the source code I realized that I needed to pass an InnerDocument object as a second parameter to the pull method so that the spring classes would be able to do the mapping correctly.

As it turns out I can navigate objects while selecting objects (I'm using "innerDocs.name" in the removeQuery) but I cannot  (or havent found a way) do the same when updating a document.

Below is how I implemented the query using MongoOperations :

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("innerDoc22", "innerDoc21");

Query removeQuery = Query.query(Criteria.where("innerDocs.name").in(ids));

WriteResult wc = 
       mongoOperations.upsert(removeQuery, 
           new Update().pull("innerDocs", 
           new InnerDocument("innerDoc22", null)), 
           OutterObject.class);

System.out.println(wc.getLastError());
```

Comment: this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/27153010/234110] worked for me better,  since _class was creating an issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the BasicDBObject instead of the InnerDocument I found this out by accident. By printing out the update object, you can see the actual mongo shell query json, which is super helpful for debugging.
:

```
Update updateObj = new Update()
         .pull("innerDocs", new BasicDBObject("innerDocs.name","innerDoc22"));

System.out.println("UPDATE OBJ: " + updateObj.toString());
```

results in:

`UPDATE OBJ: { "$pull" : { "innerDocs" : { "innerDocs.name" : "innerDoc22"}}}`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution given by med116 and I had to modify it to work :

```
Update updateObj = new Update().pull("innerDocs", new BasicDBObject("name","innerDoc22"));
```

Because otherwise there was no matching object in my array.

Comment: yes, changing "innerDocs.name" to "name"  works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

in spring data mongo,just like this:

```
//remove array's one elem
UpdateResult wc = mongoTemplate.upsert(removeQuery,new Update().pull("tags",Query.query(Criteria.where("tag").is("java"))),TestPull.class);
//remove array's multi-elem
UpdateResult wc1 = mongoTemplate.upsert(removeQuery,new Update().pull("tags",Query.query(Criteria.where("tag").in(Arrays.asList("mongo", "netty")))),TestPull.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove an element from array which does not have any other property like name  then write the query you wish and

```
Update update = new Update();
update.pull("Yourarrayname","valueyouwishtodelete");  
mongoTemplate.upsert(query,update,"collectionname");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's my solution - thanks to @ufasoli:

```java
  public Mono<ProjectChild> DeleteCritTemplChild(String id, String idch) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria
                           .where("_id")
                           .is(id)
                           .and("tasks._id")
                           .is(idch)
                     );

    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("tasks.$", null);

    return template
         // findAndModify:
         // Find/modify/get the "new object" from a single operation.
         .findAndModify(
              query, update,
              new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), ProjectChild.class
                       );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
UpdateResult updateResult = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(new Query(where("id").is(activity.getId())), new Update().pull("comments", new Query(where("id").is(commentId))), Activity.class);
```

It will generate:

```
Calling update using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "61f900e7c7b79442eb3855ea"}} and update: { "$pull" : { "comments" : { "_id" : "61fac32e3f9ab5646e016bc8"}}} in collection: activity
```