# delete a record in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-query

I  have a collection like this.

```
      System
      {
           System_id: 100,

         system_type:
        {
             [ 
              { 
            Tenant_Id: 1, 
            Tenant_Info: "check", 
            Prop_Info: ...
              }, 
              { 
             Tenant_Id: 2, 
             Tenant_Info: "sucess", 
              Prop_Info: ...
              } ]
              }
```

I need to remove the only one embedded document where the tenant_id is 1 and system_id s 100 using java api.

I have tried to delete the document. But the whole document is getting deleted. I need to delete only the embedded document where tenant_id is 1.

```
            DBCollection collection=db.getCollection("system");
    field.put("system_id",100);
    field.put("system_type.Tenant_id", 1);
    collection.remove(field);
```

Kindly guide me how to delete it? I need the output like this.

```
            System
      {
           System_id: 100,

         system_type:
        {
             [ 
             { 
             Tenant_Id: 2, 
             Tenant_Info: "sucess", 
              Prop_Info: ...
              } ]
              }
```

Comment: This question is more or less the same as another SO post: [remove an entry from array using mongodb java driver][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097621/remove-an-entry-from-array-using-mongodb-java-driver

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not deleting the whole document you need to call `update` with the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) operator instead of `remove`:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
    "System_Id", 100
);

BasicDBObject pull = new BasicDBObject(
    "$pull", new BasicDBObject(
        "system_type", new BasicDBObject(
            "Tenant_Id", 1
        )
    )
);

collection.update(query, pull);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 { $pull : { system_type : {Tenant_Id: 1} } }
```

Comment: can you help me how to do it in java