# MongoDB Java pull

Tags: java, mongodb, document, pull

i tried to remove an embedded document without succcess. 
I'm looking for the java way of following instruction:

```
db.games.update({'_id': 73}, {$pull: {'goals': {'goal': 4}}})
```

Comment: are you trying to remove? $unset is the command for removing the document. I am assuming you mean deleting a sub document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Java documentation is pretty clear, you are just constructing BSON objects to match their respective JSON counterparts as used in the shell:

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", 73);
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("goals", 
        new BasicDBObject( "goal", 4));
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$pull",fields);

    games.update( query, update );
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Bson is similar.

```
Bson query = new Document().append("_id", 73);
Bson fields = new Document().append("goals", new Document().append( "goal", 4));
Bson update = new Document("$pull",fields);

games.updateOne( query, update );
```